# how to get data from Form elemnts using spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, struts

Struts provides ActionFormBean - which helps to capture/show data in html/jsp forms. in case of Spring framework, how can we capture/show data in html/jsp.

Comment: Might I suggest reading the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-web.html). If you search the web, you can easily find lots of tutorials.

Comment: Do you mean `<form-bean`?

Answer (score 0):

This is depending on which version of Spring-MVC and which Spring controller you are using.
    Since spring version 3, the new stereotype annotation `@Controller` was introduced, we no longer need to get our controller extending any super class. And the data passed around is just a POJO in http request attribute (attribute added in `Model/ModelAndView`).
    example :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView submit(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rep,
                @ModelAttribute("formbean") @Valid MyForm form,
                BindingResult br) {
    //the form bean is passed through annotation @ModelAttribute
    form.getUserEmail()
    //you can pass data to jsp in this way
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("yourview");
    mv.addObject("yourattribute",SomeThingPassingtoJSP);

return mv;
}
```

Comment: Won't let me edit, but `@Controller` was introduced in Spring Framework v2.5.